# SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU2 AlwaysOn AG Secondary always disconnected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I'm trying to setup an AlwaysOn AG with T-SQL commands but my secondary is always in a disconnected state (when I failover, my old primary becomes disconnected).
This is not an firewall/network issue, I'm able to send messages from SQL1 to SQL2 with a TCP-sender/receiver.

The option *New Availability Group...* in SMSS also generates the same problem.
However when I'm creating an AG with *New Availability Group Wizard...* it works perfect.

This is the T-SQL statement I'm using:

```
--on primary
CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG_SQL]
FOR 
DATABASE SetupAG
REPLICA ON 'sql1'
    WITH (ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://sql1.mydomain.com:5022', 
        FAILOVER_MODE = AUTOMATIC, 
        AVAILABILITY_MODE = SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT, 
     --   BACKUP_PRIORITY = 50, 
      -- SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = NO), 
        SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC),
    N'sql2' WITH (ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://sql2.mydomain.com:5022', 
        FAILOVER_MODE = AUTOMATIC, 
        AVAILABILITY_MODE = SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT, 
     --   BACKUP_PRIORITY = 50, 
       -- SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = NO), 
        SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC);
GO
--on secondary
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG_SQL] JOIN
GO  
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG_SQL] GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE
GO
```

This is the output from different DMV's:

- dm_hadr_availability_group_states:
  [image: dm_hadr_availability_group_states]
- dm_hadr_availability_replica_states:
  [image: dm_hadr_availability_replica_states]
- dm_hadr_database_replica_states
  [image: dm_hadr_database_replica_states]

On the secondary dm_hadr_database_replica_states is empty and the database doesn't show up in sys.databases. When I look in SSMS the database is shown in 'Availability Databases'

Is this a bug in SQL Server 2016 SP1 Standard CU2 or is there something wrong with my T-SQL statement?

Comment: Can you not use `automatic seeding` option and initialize secondary before hand and see if this works ?

Comment: @shanky: without the automatic seeding option it works

Comment: @shanky: very strange behavior, I've deleted the AG without 'automatic seeding' and re-created it with 'automatic seeding' => now it works perfect.

Comment: I was not quite sure but I have faced this issue and informed to MS as well. They did not gave much attention though

Comment: Thank you for updating the question with more information. could you should the output of sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states but run it on the **secondary** along with an output of sys.databases where database_id > 4? Again, it looks like there is no database on the secondary replica.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Btw I executed the statement with 'For Database' uncommented

Comment: @FrederikVanderhaegen Thank you, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG_SQL]
FOR 
--DATABASE SetupAG
```

If this is what you're using (copied from your question) then I would expect it to say disconnected. You've created an empty availability group (no databases, or database only on the primary) so there is nothing to send or receive other than some metadata about the AG.

The fact that it works when you choose automatic seeding means you're adding a database into the AG, it's now no longer empty and should show connected (if it truly is connected).

> On the secondary dm_hadr_database_replica_states is empty and the database doesn't show up in sys.databases. When I look in SSMS the database is shown in 'Availability Databases'

This is because there is no database on the secondary server, which completely falls inline with what you've posted. The "database" shows up under the Availability Groups folder on the secondary because that's the metadata of the Availability Group, not because the database is on the secondary.

The reason it "works" with automatic seeding is because automatic seeding creates the database and seeds it on the secondary for you versus what you're doing now which is creating the AG but not preparing the database on the secondary. Thus, no database on secondary.

> Is this a bug in SQL Server 2016 SP1 Standard CU2 or is there something wrong with my T-SQL statement?

Neither, it's a process issue where the secondary wasn't prepared properly.

Comment: even when I add a database to the AG it stays disconnected.
It works when I first create the AG without 'automatic seeding' and then re-create it with 'automatic seeding'

Comment: @FrederikVanderhaegen Please add to your question the output of the following DMVs when it isn't working: sys.dm_hadr_availability_group_states , sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states , sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states .

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: It only works with automatic seeding when I first execute the same statement without automatic seeding. I then need to remove everything of the created AG, next I re-execute the same statement with automatic seeding and everything works. Executing the statement first with automatic seeding doesn't work. Or do I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: You can't create the same AG, so either you execute the create AG with automatic seeding and give the replicas the proper permissions to the AG to create or you don't. @FrederikVanderhaegen

Comment: I think there is a misunderstandig.
I remove the AG and re-create it with automatic seeding and it works.
When I create AG the first time (with automatic seeding) it doesn't work.
I need to create it first with manuel seeding (with 'Skip initial data synchronization')

Comment: @FrederikVanderhaegen I can't reproduce that. When I choose automatic seeding and then go to the secondary replica and give it the proper permissions, the database seeds without issue. If you want your specific environment looked at, I'd open up a case with Microsoft - but in transparency, I work for Microsoft. The issue of the "disconnected" state, though, is due to no databases being on the secondary.

Comment: I did some more research and the same code works in SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU1 but fails when I install CU2.